# Sticky navbar but with margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have a sticky navbar when the user scrolls, but when first landing on the page, there is a small margin of 10px at the top of the navbar (gap between the top of the navbar and the top of the page). When it scrolls down past 10px, it sticks to the top of the page.

I was referring to this tutorial and trying to adapt it without using the header: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wavyZL

However, I can't get a smooth scroll and I think it's because I can't properly adapt how to get the value in jquery code of "hdr"; instead of the height of the main-nav, I just want to get the value of the body's padding-top which is 10px. Is this my problem?

I am just frustrated that I can't seem to understand how to even search for the correct answer (if I am even identifying the correct problem).  Any advice is appreciated.

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.main-nav,
.main {
  position: relative; 
}
.main-nav {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 150;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.main-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
    }
.main {
  background: #f2f2e8;
  padding: 100px 
}
```

jquery:

```
var  mn = $(".main-nav");
mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
hdr = $('.main-nav').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
    mn.addClass(mns);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass(mns);
  }
});
```

Comment: Add a jsFiddle please :)

Answer (score 0):

omg nevermind. I figured it out. I just have to replace it with the pixel value of 10!! Still, if anyone has other resources that are good reads, please let me know.

```
var  mn = $(".main-nav");
mns = "main-nav-scrolled";

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > 10 ) {
    mn.addClass(mns);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass(mns);
  }
});
```